# PROBABILITY: counting problem solution question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am having trouble understanding the solution to this problem:

> At a state university in Maryland, there is hardly enough space for
>   students to park their cars in their own lots. Jack, a student who parks in the faculty
>   parking lot every day, noticed that none of the last 10 tickets he got was issued on a
>   Monday or on a Friday. Is it wise for Jack to conclude that the campus police do not
>   patrol the faculty parking lot on Mondays and on Fridays? Assume that police give no
>   tickets on weekends.

Solution :
"Suppose that the answer is negative and the campus police patrol the parking
lot randomly; that is, the parking lot is patrolled every day with the same probability. Let
$A$ be the event that out of 10 tickets given on random days, none is issued on a Monday
or on a Friday. If $P(A)$ is very small, we can conclude that the campus police do not
patrol the parking lot on these two days. Otherwise, we conclude that what happened is
accidental and police patrol the parking lot randomly. To find $P(A)$, note that since each
ticket has five possible days of being issued, there are $5^10$ possible ways for all tickets
to have been issued. Of these, in only $3^{10}$ ways no ticket is issued on a Monday or on
a Friday. Thus $P(A) = \frac{3^{10}}{5^{10}} = 0.006$, a rather small probability. Therefore, it is
reasonable to assume that the campus police do not patrol the parking lot on these two
days."

Sorry, I know this was a lot of text. My question is: shouldn't a small $P(A)$ indicate that it is unlikely that all 10 tickets were only issued on Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday? I don't get why the textbook claims the opposite.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  the computation of $p(A)$ assumes uniform randomness.  That is, it assumes that a ticket is equally likely to be issued on each of the five week days.  $p(A)$ small means that it is improbable, given that we observed $A$, that the assumption of uniformity is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given that Jack only got tickets on Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday.  There are two hypotheses implied to explain this.  One is that the police only patrol those three days, so nobody gets tickets on Monday or Friday.  The second is that the police patrol evenly all week and it is just chance that the last tickets were all given the middle of the week.  We are calculating the probability that the observed event would happen given that the police patrol evenly.  When we get a small number, we say the hypothesis is unlikely.

Comment: I finally understand what the author meant in his solution. Thank you very much for 
your elaboration.